# PHP Questions & Answers simple script

Tags: php, open-source

I am looking for a simple, easy-to-install, easy-to-customize PHP script that can handle questions and answers that are recorded in a database.

I have been looking for DAYS for an open source script without any luck!

Can anyone help direct me to a good OPEN-SOURCE script that does what I need?

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) on Meta

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Googling for a [Stackoveflow Clone](http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverlfow%20clone)?

You can view a comprehensive list at:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [one](http://www.question2answer.org/install.php)?

Comment: Yes, I have. But it's a complete system by itself. I need something simpler, like a simple script that only does the Q & A functionality. I haven't found any yet!

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is very old but still... Try This : http://www.coordino.com/